# Run python scripts one after another without any interruption

Tags: python, pycharm

I am running some python files in Pycharm to read some data from excel files. There are a number of files running one after another.
This is how I am doing it -

```
import A,B,C,D,E
A.main()
B.main()
C.main()
D.main()
E.main()
```

While one file is running there is some time after which the next file runs. During this time period if I click anywhere on the screen(editor/some other window) the execution gets stuck, I get no error, the execution just gets stuck. After this, I have to terminate and rerun it again. Is there a way I can resolve this? I don't want the execution to get stuck if I happen to click anywhere on the screen.

Also, all these files run correctly individually and together as long as I don't click anywhere on the screen until the execution ends.

Edit:  I need the programs to run one after another and not at the same time since the output of the first program is required by the second and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I may suggest you to use [Thread](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/). Which will help you to have different parts of your program run concurrently.

Comment: When you say concurrently, do you mean at the same time or one after the other?

Comment: @Pete maybe check the [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concurrent)

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question. I need the programs to run one after another and not at the same time since the output of the first program is required by the second. Will I be able to acheive that using thread?

Comment: @Pete , you can use Thread for your case. `final Thread t1 = new Thread(new T1()); // assume T1 is a Runnable
t1.start();
t1.join();
final Thread t2 = new Thread(new T2());
t2.start();
t2.join();`

**by calling** _join()_ method.